# Adobe Illustrator: How to Create Outlines from Shapes

Tags: adobe-illustrator, outline, shapes

I have a complex shape created with the Pen Tool from a vendor (some shapes have strokes, others don't -- and they all combine to create one final shape).  I need to convert the shape into an OUTLINE so that I can pass the file to my woodcutter to cut out the shapes on a piece of wood plank.  How can I make the outlines?  Thank you!

Comment: can't you just select the shape, give it a outline and then turn the shape white or something?

Comment: No, she's saying it's made up of multiple elements, some strokes, some fills and AI scales them differently.  A significantly complex graphic would make individual object adjustment non-trivial.  She needs some kind of "flatten" or convert stroke to fill.

Comment: Perhaps, `select all, Object -> Path -> Outline Stroke`?

Comment: Or maybe `Window -> Pathfinder, select all`. In the Pathfinder window, `Pathfinder -> Shape Modes -> Alt-Click`, then `Pathfinders -> Outline`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the screen shots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  That worked!  Now I have to clean up the drawing my deleting portions of the image.  Thank you!